# run script when scaling an instance of aws (docker container)

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, odoo

good morning,

I am using odoo in aws, and I have the problem that every time the instance scales to a higher or lower one, the Odoo system does not load correctly, it does not stop working, only the view does not display well. How can I ensure that each time it scales, it automatically executes some commands.
the odoo instance is raised with Docker.

I will greatly appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [crontab](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucrontab.htm) for linux, and have the following cron rule:

```
@reboot <command that will your app>
```

For windows server you can utilize the windows startup scripts reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn789190(v=ws.11)).

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering.  but it seems to me that it could not be because in docker it is recommended or it should only run an active process, I am not sure if the cron would be two processes.  it's all about linux.

Comment: Have you tried using CMD in docker? You can utilise it to run certain commands before your application will be served. https://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/